# Java JDBC returning duplicate result set from different calls

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am building a java web application that talks to a MYSQL database. When a request comes in there are several things that have to be done.

First I have to validate some data. To to this I have a static method that gets passed some data and verifies that it is accurate. Part of this validation requires me to query the database using another static method that returns a ResultSet

ie Web app calls Validate(String data) which calls queryData()

When I do this it runs fine.

Now, after the data has been called I call another static function that inserts some data into the database. This insertion function calls (sometimes but not always) the exact same queryData function to get the data.

ie web app call insertData(data) which calls queryData().
so the program flow is as follows

```
Webapp
|----> Validate()
          |-------->queryData()
           <-----------|
<---------|
|
|------>insertData()
          |-------->queryData()
           <-----------|
<---------|
```

I am querying the database with PreparedStatement that are locally defines in the queryData method

As I said, the validation method works fine, but when it comes to the insert method the application crashes.

I have double checked that the SQL statements are identical in both cases and I have even printed out the memory location of the result set and they are located in different places. However, when I print out the isBeforeFirst() for the result set it is true in the validation method but false in the insert method.

It seems that JDBC is returning a duplicate of the ResultSet (it is saved at a different memory location) but it isnt actually creating a new ResultSet that would be positioned before the first row .

The simple solution is to simply return the resultSet to before first but this doesnt solve the problem. It still says that the resultSet is not before first.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It would help if you posted some relevant code from your app.

Comment: Would those static methods be using any mutable data?

Comment: yes the data is mutable but nothing is being altered in the data between the cal to validate and insert.

Comment: Try close()ing the ResultSets after you're done with them.

Comment: What do you mean by "the application crashes". Do you get a stack trace?  If so, please edit your post and add the ***complete*** stack trace.  If not, explain what you mean and show any error messages you get.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me, I found the reason. Just prior to calling the queryData function I was actually modifying the data so that the result of the query function would return an empty set. After I called queryData the application would try and read data, cause an SQLException and roll back the database to before I modified anything so I never saw any difference between the queries.

Thanks everyone who tried to help.